# Pi Wordpress asks for ftp credidentials

Tags: apache-httpd, pi-b+

Recently, I have installed a LAMP server on my Raspberry Pi B+ running Raspbian 7 (Jessie) and when I try to install a plugin or theme it asks for FTP credidentials.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: how did you install wordpress? have you tried using your Pi/raspberry login? What plugin and where are you installing it from?

Comment: I installed it onto Apache 2 (Jessie) and it says it cannot connect to ftp.192.168.1.195 and I'm installing it from the wordpress directory.

Comment: Is 192.168.1.195 your Pi? Are you doing this through the wp admin panel? or are you actually trying to upload a previously downloaded packeage?

Comment: I'm trying to download a theme through the admin panel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be able to be fixed by either providing the FTP credentials in your wp-config.php file (in the root directory of the Wordpress install) or by changing ownership of the Wordpress install. I recommend the changing ownership option.

### Changing Ownership

On my Debian WordPress server (not Raspbian, but regular Debian Wheezy), my entire installation is owned by user and group named www-data.

You can check the ownership of your installation with these two lines (hit enter after each one).

```
cd /var/www
ls -l
```

That will tell you which user and group owns each file/directory in /var/www. It will be in the form of `user:group`.

You can change the entire ownership of your installation by:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ./[name of Wordpress folder]
```

That will recursively change ownership and group of everything in your WordPress folder to the user that I am pretty sure Raspbian wants to use.

### Changing Credentials

You can define some extra credentials in your wp-config.php file [according to a WordPress codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants).

```php
define( 'FTP_USER', 'username' );
define( 'FTP_PASS', 'password' );
define( 'FTP_HOST', 'ftp.example.org:21' );
```

Though I am not sure if you also then have to figure out configuring the FTP server on the RPi.

Hope this gets you going!

Comment: Changing the entire ownership of the folder did the trick for me. Much thanks :-)!